# How to go back to Ubuntu 16.04 from Xubuntu

Tags: 16.04, unity, xubuntu, xfce, desktop-environments

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 then I have switched to Xubuntu using the following commands

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop  
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install xfce4
sudo apt purge --autoremove unity unity8
```

Now I would like to go back into Ubuntu. What should I do?